# Extract column from text in memory

Tags: r, readr

I'm looking for a fast way to read in a single column from tab-separated text that lives as a character vector in memory.

I'm using a file format specific to my field that roughly resembles a compressed tsv file. It is fast and easy to read in a subset of lines from such file, but unfeasible to read in data directly with `read.table()`, `data.table::fread()` or `readr::read_tsv()` due to memory limitations (and the rows I need aren't known a priori).

So, I end up with a character vector in memory, with an element for every line, but with the tab separators still in there. I'm a bit puzzled on how to quickly extract a specific column from this text. In the example below, what is the fastest way to extract the third column? There aren't any 'surprises' in the text such as comments or quoted names, but in my real case the columns don't have a fixed width. The fastest method I've found so far is to use the `readr::read_tsv()` function.

```r
library(readr)

set.seed(0)
# About 88Mb of memory
n_examples <- 1e6
text <- paste(
  as.character(as.hexmode(sample(n_examples))),
  as.character(as.hexmode(sample(n_examples))),
  as.character(as.hexmode(sample(n_examples))),
  as.character(as.hexmode(sample(n_examples))),
  sep = "\t"
)

fun_read.table <- function(x, i) {
  read.table(
    text = x, sep = "\t", 
    colClasses = c("character", "character", "character", "character")
  )[[i]]
}

fun_read_tsv <- function(x, i) {
  read_tsv(file = I(x), col_select = all_of(i), 
           col_types = "cccc", col_names = LETTERS[1:4])[[1]]
}

bm <- bench::mark(
  fun_read.table(text, 3),
  fun_read_tsv(text, 3), 
  min_iterations = 5
)
#> Warning: Some expressions had a GC in every iteration; so filtering is disabled.

print(bm)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 13
#>   expression                   min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr
#>   <bch:expr>              <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int>
#> 1 fun_read.table(text, 3)    1.34s    1.57s     0.619    93.2MB    1.11      5
#> 2 fun_read_tsv(text, 3)   879.36ms 903.72ms     1.10     35.1MB    0.219     5
#> # ... with 6 more variables: n_gc <dbl>, total_time <bch:tm>, result <list>,
#> #   memory <list>, time <list>, gc <list>
```

Below are some alternatives that I've tried, but weren't faster than `read_tsv()`. The `data.table::fread()` method was surprisingly slow due to it writing the input text to a temporary file first. I haven't managed to figure out a regex-based method to capture the third column, so I don't know if that would be faster.

```r
library(data.table)
#> Warning: package 'data.table' was built under R version 4.1.1

fun_tstrsplit <- function(x, i) {
  tstrsplit(x, "\t", keep = i)[[1]]
}

fun_fread <- function(x, i) {
  fread(
    text = x, sep = "\t",
    colClasses = c("character", "character", "character", "character"),
    select = i
  )[[1]]
}

fun_scan <- function(x, i) {
  ncols <- lengths(regmatches(x[[1]], gregexpr("\t", x[[1]]))) + 1
  scan(
    text = x, sep = "\t", what = "", quiet = TRUE
  )[seq_along(x) %% ncols == i]
}
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Could you eloborate which `data.table` version you tried? I tried to reproduce but even with `setDTthreads(1L)` `fread` was faster than `read_tsv` for me.

Comment: I tried v1.14.2 and on my machine it takes a median of ~6.9 sec regardless of using 6 or 1 thread. On my linux machine it takes 5.1 seconds. Do you happen to have an SSD that writing to a file is faster than what I get on my HDD?

Comment: True that, I have a SSD. You could try to set `TMPDIR=/dev/shm` before starting R to dump the file on memory disk instead of HDD.

Answer (score 4):

A bespoke function written with Rcpp worked fastest for me here (a bit more than twice as fast as `read_tsv`), and uses about a quarter of the memory allocation of `read_tsv`, even though it involves some copying and could probably be optimised.

I've included a version using `sub` too, but this is slower than `read_tsv`, although again it doesn't require much memory.

```r
Rcpp::cppFunction("

std::vector<std::string> fun_rcpp(CharacterVector a, int col) {
  if(col < 1) Rcpp::stop(\"col must be a positive integer\");
  std::vector<std::string> b = Rcpp::as<std::vector<std::string>>(a);
  std::vector<std::string> result(a.size());
  for(uint32_t i = 0; i < a.size() ; i++)
  {
    int n_tabs = 0;
    std::string entry = \"\";
    for(uint16_t j = 0; j < b[i].size(); j++)              
    {
      if(n_tabs == (col - 1) & b[i][j] != '\\t') entry.push_back(b[i][j]);
      if((b[i][j]) == '\\t') n_tabs++;
      if(n_tabs == col) break;
    }
    result[i] = entry;
  }
  return result;
}

")

fun_sub <- function(x, i)
{
  s <- paste0("^", paste0(rep(".*?\t", i - 1), collapse = ""), "(.*?)\t.*$")
  sub(s, "\\1", x)
}
```

These functions both give the expected output:

```r
identical(fun_read_tsv(text, 3), fun_rcpp(text, 3))
#> [1] TRUE

identical(fun_read_tsv(text, 3), fun_sub(text, 3))
#> [1] TRUE
```

And the benchmarks are shown here for comparison:

```
bench::mark(
  fun_read.table(text, 3),
  fun_read_tsv(text, 3),
  fun_sub(text, 3),
  fun_rcpp(text, 3),
  min_iterations = 5
)

#> # A tibble: 4 x 13
#>   expression                   min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc
#>   <bch:expr>              <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>
#> 1 fun_read.table(text, 3)    1.35s    1.35s     0.738   93.23MB    5.17      1     7
#> 2 fun_read_tsv(text, 3)   788.86ms 792.35ms     1.26    36.04MB    0.314     4     1
#> 3 fun_sub(text, 3)           1.27s    1.29s     0.777    7.63MB    0.194     4     1
#> 4 fun_rcpp(text, 3)       379.02ms 381.17ms     2.62     7.63MB    0.655     4     1
#> # ... with 5 more variables: total_time <bch:tm>, result <list>, memory <list>,
#   time <list>, gc <list>
```

Note that the Rcpp function behaves pretty much as expected, with appropriate errors emitted if you give a column number of less than 1 or use the wrong variable type to select a column. However, if you select a column number greater than the number of columns present it will return a vector of empty strings rather than throwing an error. You could easily write an R wrapper to the C++ function if you wanted different behaviour here, such as an error or a vector of `NA`

Comment: Thanks Allan, this is great and much faster! Also good to see the regex option laid out so clearly!